# Debugging multiple GDB files

Tags: c++, debugging

I am debugging a C++ code which is divided into multiple files. The code which I am debugging has 6 errors in total, both syntax and logical. I have found one error but I could not figure out a way to solve the rest. I have referred to multiple online sources including but not limited to YouTube (Bucky C++), Tutorial's Point, Geeks for Geeks and more.

My code is in this [link](https://onlinegdb.com/SkpueFgUN).

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Debuggers can't help with syntax errors.

Comment: before to debug you need to compile, and you code cannot be compiled because of the errors it contains

Comment: Forget YouTube and tutorials. Get yourself [a proper book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn the language and how to develop software with it

Comment: Always solve syntax errors one by one. First error is pretty undestandable: `error: ‘class billType’ has no member named ‘setRoomRent’`.

Comment: I've got to say, though, that first error is pretty clear. What about it are you struggling with?

Comment: Can you see something about your `setDisDate` definition that differs from all the others in that file?

Comment: By the way, for future reference that website is confusingly named. These are not "GDB files" and that is not GDB. It is an online tool/IDE/debugger combo that probably invokes GDB at some point down the line (post-compilation) but it is not itself GDB.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm struggling with classes.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson you just have to add the declaration of setRoomRent and to add a missing prefix for setDisDate, see my answer

Comment: I'm sorry but "I'm struggling" isn't actionable intelligence; you need to tell us specifically what the problem is otherwise we cannot help you with it.

Comment: @bruno It still didn't solve the issue. Now, I am getting a different error.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson the link is not updated with your new version

Comment: @bruno It should be now. I was testing it locally.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  I edited my answer, but is a trivial error, you do not understand compiler error ?

Comment: @bruno Thanks. It works.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson ok, but you need to understand compiler/link errors, sorry but these errors was simple ... and me I need to sleep ^^

Comment: @bruno, yes I understand. My teacher vaguely explains the concept, which is why many students are looking for other resources. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  *billType.h* add declaration of operation `void setRoomRent(double charges);`

In *patientTypeImp.cpp* replace `void setDisDate(int disDay, int disMth, int disYear)` by `void patientType::setDisDate(int disDay, int disMth, int disYear)`

after you will be able to compile ... then debug

---

(about link error after previous error fix)

You missed to define `void doctorType::setSpeciality(string)`, it is only declared

just add the probable definition

```
void doctorType::setSpeciality(string spl)
{
    speciality = spl;
}
```